# Can a class be aliased in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, class, interface

In a namespace, is it possible to provide an alias for a class?  And if not, why not?

By example, if I had several libraries of things that were derived from a contained, but named base class, but wanted to alias that as "BaseClass", while retaining its actual class name (i.e. "HtmlControl").

Then consumers could always come along and extend from HtmlControls.BaseClass, without having to figure out which class it really comes from.

Comment: No. It's not possible to create an "alias". The `using` approach creates a *local* alias -- it is not exposed beyond the [source] code in scope. A dummy type may be able to simulate an "alias".

Comment: I am curious what you are hoping to get out of this if you were actually able to do this.  Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @poindexter, let me see if I can explain.  Say I am providing a library intended for the consumer to use the classes or derive new ones from the base class.  Continuing with my example, I want consumers to derive new Html controls from my base class.  Now add that I have 5 or 50 or 500 namesspace segments following the pattern, instead of the consumer having to look up documentation on each, he can check if I provided the "hint" com.example.BaseClass he can quickly derive from, rather than reading the documentation for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't an ideal way to do this in C#/.NET. What you can do is have a public BaseClass that inherits from an internal class. You can change this inheritance internally without breaking your consumers as long as the interface to the class remains intact.

```
public class PublicBaseClass : SomeInternalClass {

}
```

Consumers inherit from `PublicBaseClass`, and as long as you are careful, you can change what `SomeInternalClass` is as you wish.

Comment: `public` classes cannot inherit from `internal` classes - it is a compilation error.

Comment: Ah that is right. So really what the OP wants isn't too doable IMO.

Comment: Public classes can inherit from classes with an Internal or Private constructor.  Unfortunately, the only way to use a class with a private constructor is to have other classes nested inside it.

Comment: @Greer, right, I was looking for a straight up alias, which as you guys pointed out does not exist in the language.

Answer (score 4):

```
using SomeClass = Large.Namespace.Other.FunkyClass;

class Foo : SomeClass
{
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as he wants consumers to receive the alias. Here the consumer is creating their own alias.

Comment: This aliasing must be done by the implementer (the one deriving from `BaseClass`/`HtmlControl` in the example).  It isn't useful for hiding details from implementers.

Comment: True. The only other option is to create more classes which "hide" the detail. ie: pointless classes that don't add value. Those people who use/inherit those classes *want* the detail. Attempting to hide the "detail" purely by changing the name and adding another class to the hierarchy is pointless. If the new name masks the whole idea of what the customers would implement, you're introducing a world of hurt as people discover behaviour they never expected. Using aliasing, or don't use anything at all.

Comment: @OJ: There are some inheritance scenarios where one or more classes which should be exposed to outside consumers needs access to the private members (including possibly the constructor) of a class which should not.  This works out very nicely except that the class ends up being exposed with an annoying multi-part name.  If aliases could be introduced in the module exporting the class, such names wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @OJ: But it would add value.. the value of a "hint" towards which is the base class for a lib thats meant to provide one, and providing derived classes.

Comment: It's good to see a healthy discussion :) I don't believe that adding classes is the resolution. This is where quality documentation comes in. but that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dummy class that just inherits `HtmlControl` without adding any other functionality:

```
public class BaseClass : HtmlControl {}
```

Comment: This obviously comes with the proviso that `HtmlControl` is `public` (not `internal`). But that goes for all the suggestions posted so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know of is to customize your using statement:

```
using BaseClass = HtmlControls.BaseClass;
```

This is normally used to avoid ambiguity between classes with the same name in different used namespaces, without having to fully qualify one or the other. Your devs would have to include it in every code file, so probably not a good solution for what you're doing.

As far as deriving from `BaseClass` without knowing what you are actually deriving from, not possible. The compiler must, at some level, know what and where the parent class is, meaning it must be statically defined somewhere in code.